# How to prove that two elementary equivalent structures embed in a common structure?

Tags: model-theory

Given $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ two structures, I want to show that there exists $\mathcal{N}$ such that $\mathcal{N}$ is an elementary extension of both $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$.

To do so, I am looking for a model of both elementary diagrams.
By compactness theorem I just need to show that $\mathrm{diag}_\mathrm{el}\mathcal{M}_1\cup\{\phi(\bar d)\}$ is consistent for all statement $\phi(\bar d)$ in $\mathrm{diag}_\mathrm{el}\mathcal{M}_2$ where $\bar d$ are constants in the diagram, that is elements $\mathrm{dom}(\mathcal{M}_2)$.

I know by elementary equivalence that $\mathcal{M_1}\models\exists y\phi(y)$ and I get an element $\bar b$ of $M_1$ but I don't know how to conclude that $\mathcal{M_1}\cup\{\bar b\}\models\mathrm{diag}_\mathrm{el}\mathcal{M}_1\cup\{\phi(\bar d)\}$ rigorously since $\bar b$ is already in $M_1$ it seems like I have to consider a constant associated with $\bar b$ but I don't know how to do it/how it would interact with the rest of the elements of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much there. To make $\mathcal{M}_1$ into a model of $\mathrm{diag}_\mathrm{el}\mathcal{M}_1\cup\{\phi(\bar d)\}$ you have to extend it to a structure with an interpretation for the new constant symbols in $\bar d$. This is done by interpreting the constant symbols in $\bar d$ as $\bar b$.